# Oracle SQL command not properly ended while running a subquery through Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to fetch all the columns present in a table with this subquery

I am calling my code with these parameters

```
let idsquery="select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = (select table_id from ids_tables where table_name ='ZR_INVOICE_DETAILS');";
idsFunction(idsquery,icallback);
```

here is my code

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const idsObj=require('../config').idsObj;
let error;
let user;
function idsconnection(query,callback){
  // var query="select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id=2016";
  console.log(query);
  oracledb.getConnection(
      idsObj,
      function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('failed to connect',err);
          error = err;
          return;
        }
        connection.execute(query, [], function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('failed to execute',err);
            error = err;
            return;
          }
          // console.log('column names are',result.metaData);
          // console.log('rows are',result.rows);
          // console.log('rows count is',result.rows.length);

          connection.close(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('failed to close connection',err);
            }
            // console.log('callback is ',callback);
            callback(result)
          });
        })
      }
  );
}

module.exports=idsconnection;
```

this code works fine when I call it

```
let idsquery="select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = 2012;";
idsFunction(idsquery,icallback);
```

like this

but it is giving this error when I execute the 1st query

```
failed to execute { [Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended] errorNum:933, offset: 125 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you said does work is exactly as you showed - including the semicolon at the end? I don't think that should be there, in either version, and it would cause that error in JDBC, dynamic SQL etc. calls - but not sure about Node.

Comment: The code you say works wouldn't actually work with the semi-colon at the end of the SQL statement. After you remove the semi-colon, which is causing the current error your seeing, you'll need to change the equality operator to use either 'in' or 'exists'. I prefer 'in', but be careful with null values and 'in'.

Comment: @AlexPoole thank you so much for the comment , I removed the semicolon and it worked.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I don't need to use IN , cause I know my query will definitely return a unique value.

Comment: @pranaytanniru Ah, sorry. If it's a single row fetch then you're good. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @alex-poole in a comment, the issue (or first issue) will be that you have a trailing semi-colon in the statement:

```
let idsquery="select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = (select table_id from ids_tables where table_name ='ZR_INVOICE_DETAILS');";
```

Change it to:

```
let idsquery="select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = (select table_id from ids_tables where table_name ='ZR_INVOICE_DETAILS')";
```

Oracle SQL doesn't include semi-colons.  Confusingly, semi-colons are needed for PL/SQL, and are also used for SQL by some tools like SQL*Plus to say "this is the end of the statement, execute everything before here".

A (potential) second issue is that you are not using bind variables.  You probably want to do:

```
let query="select COLUMN_Name from ids_columns where table_id = (select table_id from ids_tables where table_name = :tn)";

connection.execute(query, ['ZR_INVOICE_DETAILS'], function(err, result) { . . .
```

Bind variables improve scalability and help prevent SQL Injection security problems.

Answer (score 2):

Query itself looks OK. The error mentions "offset: 125" which points to the closing parenthesis.

Would it help if you rewrite that query so that it uses join (and avoid subqueries), e.g.

```
let idsquery="SELECT column_name FROM ids_columns c JOIN ids_tables t ON c.table_id = t.table_id WHERE t.table_name = 'ZR_INVOICE_DETAILS';";
```

Comment: No, it didn't work, Its giving the same error when I tried the query you mentioned.a
I removed the semi colon in your query and it worked.
But thanks to you ,  I learnt  how to rewrite the query using joins.